# Is it true for all functions that $f^{-1}(A - B) = f^{-1}(A) - f^{-1}(B)$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Is it true for all functions that

$$f^{-1}(A - B) \stackrel{?}{=} f^{-1}(A) - f^{-1}(B)$$

with $A$ and $B$ being sets, and $A - B$ being the difference between the sets $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an _isolated question_. Without further context and providing your insights towards finding a solution, your are very unlikely to be answered. Your question might also be closed.

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Can you find a counterexample?

Comment: I agree with @geetha290krm ... what happens when you try to prove this?  First, make sure you know the definitions of the things used in the equation.

Comment: The editor has done a mistake. They didn't include in the edited post, the fact that $A$ and $B$ are sets, which was a part of the original version of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, pre-images are very well behaved. In particular, the proposed relation holds:
\begin{align*}
x\in f^{-1}(A - B) & \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in A - B\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow f(x)\in A\cap B^{c}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (f(x)\in A)\wedge(f(x)\not\in B)\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in f^{-1}(A))\wedge(x\not\in f^{-1}(B))\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\in f^{-1}(A) - f^{-1}(B)
\end{align*}

and we are done.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No, the inverse function in general are not "linear".

For example if $f(x)=x^2$, then $f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

It is not in general true that $f^{-1}(A-B)=f^{-1}(A)-f^{-1}(B)$, because $\sqrt{A-B}\ne\sqrt{A}-\sqrt{B}$

Comment: Dear @Gerald, I think you are mistaking the definitions involved. Here $A$ and $B$ are sets, not numbers.

Comment: Dear @ÁtilaCorreia, can you provide constructive criticism? For example, do you mean that the interpretation of $f^{-1}(A)$ supposed to be the pre-image of $A$?

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia You are, of course, correct.  However, this confusion is a good reason to be more restricted in your edits in the future.  The original version of the question, while perhaps not the best written, explicitly mentioned $A,B$ are sets.  If I were you, I would have kept those details to avoid such confusion. (by themselves, tags generally aren't sufficient to prevent confusion)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks for the comment. Indeed, I should not have removed the comments from the OP. Should I edit the body of the question to include such considerations?

Comment: @Gerald Yes, in this notation, $$f^{-1}(A) = \{x : f(x) \in A \text{ and } x \text{ is in the domain of } f\}$$ is the pre-image of $A$ and $$A - B = \{x : x\in A \text{ and } x \not\in B\}$$ is the relative complement of $B$ in $A$.